# Opencart unable to display variable sent from controller in view

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, controller, opencart

I am having difficulty getting a variable to display on the product page in Opencart. I have added a SQL query to catalog/model/catalog/product.php file as below:

```
public function getLargeItems($product_id) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "oc_product_attribute WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND attribute_id=17  AND (text LIKE '10lt' OR text LIKE '30lt' OR text LIKE '50lt')");

    return $query->row;
}
```

I then added the following to the catalog/controller/product/product.php file:

```
$large_items = $this->model_catalog_product->getLargeItems($product_id);
```

Finally I added the following to the /catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/product/product.tpl page:

```
<?php if ($large_items) { ?>

<h1>Tree</h1>

<?php } ?>
```

And it returns Undefined variable: large_items in /catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/product/product.tpl

I am at a bit of a loss now. Is anyone able to see by my code why its unable to pull the variable from the controller?

I've tried simplifying it by adding $large_items = "Hello" to the controller to see if I can echo this on the view page however it still cant see the variable.

The version of Opencart is 2.3.0.2

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by doing two things:

Removing oc_ from the query as the prefix is already defined, I was however only able to notice this after discovering that controller changes dont get picked up without clearing the cache in the admin panel > modifications > click the blue refresh button.

I was then able to see the broken query in the php logs.

The issue was my shoddy code, but I hope that the cache refresh information is useful to others if they get stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you must remove `oc_` from `"oc_product_attribute WHERE product_id =...` because prefix is already defined like `" . DB_PREFIX . "`.

Next you not properly defined `$large_items` in your controller. must be:
`$data['large_items'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getLargeItems($product_id);`
then you can get it on your .tpl like `$large_items` or in .twig {{ large_items }}

in twig your code should be:

```
{% if large_items %}

<h1>Tree</h1>

{% endif %}
```

Good luck